# redis (error) ERR operation not permitted

Tags: redis

all of a sudden my redis database has started to give errors on some connections:

```
(error) ERR operation not permitted
```

I've restarted the redis service and am connecting to it with the client using the correct auth key, it connects everytime but only allows db operations through the client only some of the time.

Comment: Is it an hosted database? If so what's your provider?

Comment: It's self hosted on Amazon ec2.  I'm connecting to it with redis-cli as well as various node and .net clients.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

search for the line above in your on the redis config file to check if you have a password set:

```
requirepass foobared
```

If that line is not commented out, then you need to do this:

```
$redis-cli redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH foobared 
OK
```

Comment: Note that the AUTH command only takes one argument: the password. The "OK" up there shouldn't be typed in -- that's the response you'd get for a successful AUTH call.

Comment: that worked for me, thanks.. btw what about this command -> redis-cli -a <your-password>? i tried this but it's not working..